# Android ACRA custom ReportSender send method called twice

Tags: java, android, acra

I wanted to add crashlogging to my android app, i decided to use ACRA library (ver 4.6.1). I wrote a custom report sender calling a webmethods service (backend of my app). For some reason send method of my ReportSender is called twice with the same CrashReportData object. I added code which crashes app to method called by one of the buttons, and the button method is called only once. I suspect that app crashes for the second time from inside the library code, but debugger wont stop on a breakpoint inside send method so i can't be sure. Here's code for ACRA initialization :

```
@ReportsCrashes(
    mode = ReportingInteractionMode.DIALOG,
    resToastText = R.string.crash_toast_text, // optional, displayed as soon as the crash occurs, before collecting data which can take a few seconds
    resDialogText = R.string.crash_dialog_text,
    resDialogIcon = android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info, //optional. default is a warning sign
    resDialogTitle = R.string.crash_dialog_title, // optional. default is your application name
    resDialogCommentPrompt = R.string.crash_dialog_comment_prompt, // optional. When defined, adds a user text field input with this text resource as a label
    resDialogOkToast = R.string.crash_dialog_ok_toast,  // optional. displays a Toast message when the user accepts to send a report.
    customReportContent = { ReportField.APP_VERSION_CODE, ReportField.APP_VERSION_NAME, ReportField.ANDROID_VERSION, ReportField.PHONE_MODEL, ReportField.CUSTOM_DATA, ReportField.STACK_TRACE, ReportField.LOGCAT, ReportField.USER_COMMENT } )
public class MHABApplication extends Application
{
@Override
public void onCreate() {


    // The following line triggers the initialization of ACRA
    ACRA.init(this);
    CrashESBReportSender esbSender = new CrashESBReportSender();
    ACRA.getErrorReporter().setReportSender(esbSender);

    super.onCreate();
}
```

`

Thanks!

Comment: CrashESBReportSender esbSender = new CrashESBReportSender();
ACRA.getErrorReporter().setReportSender(esbSender); What is the use of this..?

Comment: not sure, copied from documentation (probably registering the custom sender) :
https://github.com/ACRA/acra/wiki/AdvancedUsage#implementing-your-own-sender

Answer (score 0):

Show your Android log when the crash is reported twice.
It could be that the device throught it was unable to send the first time so it resent. This can happen if the connection to your server is timed out by the client. You can mitigate that by adjusting the socket timeout.

https://github.com/ACRA/acra/wiki/AdvancedUsage#adjusting-the-socket-timeout

Comment: New URL seems to be like this: https://github.com/ACRA/acra/wiki/Report-Destinations#adjusting-the-socket-timeout

Comment: But how can I set the socketTimeout option when using my own ReportSenderFactory class?